# Is the C# language a Microsoft product?

Tags: .net

I am proofing my thesis and I am wondering how I should describe the language that I used

- Microsoft C-Sharp (C#)
- C-Sharp (C#)
- C#
- C# and the Microsoft .NET Framework

Combinations of, or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C# language is an ECMA standard. The standard was submitted by Hewlett-Packard, Intel and Microsoft and it was developed within Microsoft. The standard never uses the term "Microsoft C#". Hence, I would label it initially as *"the C# programming language, developed by Microsoft"* and subsequently I would only reference it as *"C#"* or *"C# programming language"*, just like the standard does ([ECMA-334 pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

"[Microsoft Visual C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C_Sharp)" if you're talking about their compiler/implementation, otherwise just "C#" in my opinion (feel free to qualify with "programming language" if you care to). The version number is definitely helpful too. Remember, it's a [published standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Standardization) and theirs is not the only implementation (though they did come up with it).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "The Microsoft C# programming language and the Microsoft .NET Framework version 3.5 SP1".

Answer (score 0):

How about "Microsoft's C# language implementation on the Microsoft .NET Framework"?